# Select distinct child elements from repeating parent using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, unique

I want to select distinct child elements from repeating parent using XPath 1.0. 
Following is the XML:

```
<parent>
<something>
    <catalog>
        <title>AAA</title>
        <artist>111</artist>
    </catalog>
    <catalog>
        <title>AAA</title>
        <artist>111</artist>
    </catalog>
    <catalog>
        <title>BBB</title>
        <artist>222</artist>
    </catalog>
</something>
<something>
    <catalog>
        <title>CCC</title>
        <artist>333</artist>
    </catalog>
    <catalog>
        <title>BBB</title>
        <artist>222</artist>
    </catalog>
    <catalog>
        <title>CCC</title>
        <artist>333</artist>
    </catalog>
</something>
<something>
    <catalog>
        <title>AAA</title>
        <artist>111</artist>
    </catalog>
    <catalog>
        <title>BBB</title>
        <artist>222</artist>
    </catalog>
    <catalog>
        <title>CCC</title>
        <artist>333</artist>
    </catalog>
</something>
</parent>
```

Now, in the expected output I just want to pick the distinct `catalog` elements across the entire XML so that I can process it further. So the output should be:

```
<catalog>
    <title>AAA</title>
    <artist>111</artist>
</catalog>
<catalog>
    <title>BBB</title>
    <artist>222</artist>
</catalog>
<catalog>
    <title>CCC</title>
    <artist>333</artist>
</catalog>
```

I looked at some existing solutions, like `not(. = ../following-sibling::*)` but it is not helping me because I am trying to pick distinct items across repeating parent items. Please help and sorry for the outrageous xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following axis instead of following-sibling, it will search all document starting from the current context:

```
//catalog[not(. = following::catalog)]
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks, it works like a charm. Sorry for acknowledging after long. I have been away.